# Bootstrap Hamburger menu doesn't show up on iphone, shows up on android

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a hamburger menu, it shows up on all android platforms and pads, but not on iphones. It also appears on the google "responsive tester" for iphones.

I've look and searched everywhere for an answer, tried changing css, but nothing works. You can check out the site at https://www.zonnismusic.com. I have installed bootstrap files properly and they all seem to work.

Also, this is my first time ever asking a question on stack overflow, so any suggestions as to how I can make it better would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone in advance.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg w-100 navbarmain">
       <div class="logo"> <img <?php the_custom_logo()?> > </div>
       <button class="navbar-toggler mybutton" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            </span>
       </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" >
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location'=>'primary',
        'container'=>false,
        'menu_class'=>'nav custom-nav-items nav-item navbar-nav',
            )
       );?>
       </div>
       </div>
     </nav>


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.logo {
height:6vh;
margin-top: -23px;
margin-left: -1%;;
position: absolute;
}

.navbarmain {
margin-top: 2vh;
height:10vh;
}
.mybutton {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}
.container1 {
margin-top:-5px;
margin-left:70vw;
}
.bar1,.bar2, .bar3  {
height:5px;
width:30px;
}
}
```

I expect the hamburger menu to appear on an iphone. It appears on android, but not iphone. No error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out!!! I was applying my .css to the .container1, when i should have been applying it to .navbar-toggler-icon.